# Get_text() is not working

Tags: selenium

```
list = []
for item in webElement:
    list.append(item.get_text())

print(list)

<div class='class'>    <p>text1<\p>    <p>text2<\p>    <p>text3<\p><\>
```

The output is [None], I was wondering if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [`.text`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) as below  :-

```
list = []
for item in webElement:
  list.append(item.text)

print(list)
```

If unfortunately above does not work try using `get_attribute("textContent")` as :-

```
list.append(item.get_attribute("textContent"))
```

Or try using `get_attribute("innerHTML")` as :-

```
list.append(item.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```